# std::cout sentry_base dead lock in visual studio

Tags: c++

I have created a program that needs to disable cout and do some color output and then re-enable cout.  I do this redirecting cout to a string stream after creating a ostream with the old cout buffer.

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::ostream out(std::cout.rdbuf());
std::cout.rdbuf(ss.rdbuf());
//change color here.
out << "stuff";
//change color back.
std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());
std::cout << ss.rdbuf();
```

The problem that I am having is that an internal mechanism in the stream buffer called a *sentry* gets dead locked at sentry_base if another thread is trying to output to cout.
[image]
Calling _Lock and _Unlock on cout fixes this problem.

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::ostream out(std::cout.rdbuf());
std::cout.rdbuf()->_Lock();
std::cout.rdbuf(ss.rdbuf());
//change color here.
out << "stuff";
//change color back.
std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());
std::cout.rdbuf()->_Unlock();
std::cout << ss.rdbuf();
```

My question is this: How do I fix this problem without using _Lock and _Unlock? The issue with them is that they are not standard, so I cant use them.

I need a method that would work with other external library code that uses traditional std::cout.

Comment: Seems like you could use two wrapper subclasses one with and one without locks depending on which environment.

Comment: That looks like the way I will have to go. I cant fight the OS on its under-the-hood output implementation.  Another option I have been tossing around is immediately taking over std::cout before any other threads have a change to use it. I would create a separate thread to control the   the new faux std::cout buffer and actually write it to the real std output buffer in a more thread safe way.  Just an idea.  Trying to control another library without being able to change it is the funnest thing I have done in a while.